# What does "pram" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I heard in the description of the movie [Who Framed Roger Rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Framed_Roger_Rabbit):

> Donald, in devil horns, slowly opens the upright and aims a cannon at Daffy who **prams**.

I first thought it was "preens" or "prances," but the audio doesn't sound like it. I looked up "pram", but the word doesn't have a meaning close to what the context asks for. I am putting the [audio here for reference](https://clyp.it/jz3zp11g) (available through an audio sharing site Clyp). It describes Daffy swiping his hair back in a smug gesture, as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misheard it. The word is the verb [**to primp**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/primp), not *pram*:

> to make small changes to your hair, make-up, clothes, etc. in order to look more attractive

Example sentence:

> She primped her hair in front of the mirror.